# updating php red hat

Tags: php, redhat

I am trying to install PHP MVC framework Symfony.
When I go to the check requirements page it says that I have to update my php to version 5.3.17+.

I have an VPS with RedHat. I am totally new in this so I hoped people here could help me with the commands how to upgrade it to php 5.3.17+ or 5.4 (which I prefer).

PHP needs to have PDO working

Comment: if you downvote please give an argument.

Comment: For a start: Redhat what? There are at least 3 major versions in use, two of them widespread (v5 & v6) and one out of support (v4). Also: What did you try? [SF] is no "do my work for me" site.

Comment: Also, no one is required to give a comment for up- or downvotes for good reasons.

Comment: @SvenW No one is required. But it could be usefull instead of only downvoting ( there was some big article about this on one of the meta sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Red Hat and derived distributions, I recommend using the [remi repository](http://rpms.remirepo.net/) to get PHP packages (and symfony) to ensure a stable system (though with necessary bugfix updates as well). It currently contains PHP 5.3.19, symfony 1.4.20 and symfony2 2.1.3.